# Is there a way to identify lines been deleted by a commit via API in github

Tags: git, github

For a given commit, I need to identify the exact line numbers of each file ( which are been affected by the same commit) been deleted from that commit. For example from the commit hash [d53489b5b2ad907d01957eb50ddf12dc3611d127](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/commit/d53489b5b2ad907d01957eb50ddf12dc3611d127) following files are been affected

> components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/pom.xml
>
> components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/analytics/apim/internal/TemplateManagerInitializer.java
>
> components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/analytics/apim/internal/TemplateManagerInitializerComponent.java

what I need is to identify line numbers like `86, 96 ,105, 108` which are been deleted from `components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/analytics/apim/internal/TemplateManagerInitializer.java` file. The reason for doing this is that I need to identify who has commited the deleted lines to the file. I tried `blame` view in github web interface but it is not showing details about deleted lines Is there a workaround to achieve what I need?. Thanks in advance